# Textfield not enabled in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I am trying to create a TextField in SwiftUI, Its successfully created but not enabled. I don't understand why its not enabled. please see the blow code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct About: View {
    
    static var about:String = ""//some very very very long description string to be initially wider than screen"
    static var testBinding = Binding<String>(get: { about }, set: {
        //        print("New value: \($0)")
        about = $0 } )
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView{
            GeometryReader{geometry in
                ZStack{
                    VStack{
                        
                        Username()
                        aboutu()
                        profission()
                        youtubeurl()
                        website()
                        submitbutton()
                        
                    }
                }.padding(.all,10)
                
            }
        }
    }
}




struct About_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        About()
    }
}

struct Username: View {
    
    @State var name: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Your Name", text: $name)
            .padding()
            .background(lightGreyColor)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
    }
}

struct aboutu: View {
    var body: some View {
        MultilineTextField("About You", text: About.testBinding)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(Color.gray))
            .padding(.bottom,10)
    }
}

struct profission: View {
    
    @State var profession: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Your Profession", text: $profession)
            .padding()
            .background(lightGreyColor)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
    }
}

struct youtubeurl: View {
    
    @State var youtube: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Your Youtube URL", text: $youtube)
            .padding()
            .background(lightGreyColor)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
    }
}

struct website: View {
    
    @State var website: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Your WebSite", text: $website)
            .padding()
            .background(lightGreyColor)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
    }
}

struct submitbutton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            
        }){
            Text("Submit")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.system(size:14))
                .padding()
                .padding(5)
            
        }.frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many text fields in your snapshot, which one is disabled? Would you provide minimal reproducible example?

Comment: non of them are enabled

Comment: its working fine now its because of scroll view. i moved it in to ZStack, then its started working.